# Closure of a subspace with respect to a inner product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I just have a question in general. If we are trying to show that a subspace of a vector space is a closed subspace, I know we need to prove that all convergent sequences in that subspace converge to a limit in that set. But if the subspace is defined in terms of the inner product, for example:

A = {f is a continuous function on C[0,1]: < f,sinh > = 0} and we knew that < f,sinh > is a continuous function of f, why would this imply A is a closed subspace?

Comment: write your thoughts about question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know topology, by the definition the map $\phi$ is continuous if the preimage $\phi^{-1}(A)$ is open given that the set $A$ is open. Equivalently, $\phi^{-1}(B)$ is closed whenever $B$ is closed. In your case
$$
  \phi(f) = \langle f,\sin \rangle
$$
is a continuous function from $C([0,1])$ to $\Bbb R$, and since $B = \{0\}$ is a closed set, your $A = \phi^{-1}(B)$ is closed as well. Clearly, it is also a linear space, so it is a closed subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\phi(f)=<f,sinh>$ is a continuous function of $f$, $\phi^{-1}(0)=A$ will be closed.